# How to format a Windows path to a Unix path on Cygwin command line

Tags: windows, unix, sed, path, cygwin

When using Cygwin, I frequently copy a Windows path and manually edit all of the slashes to Unix format.  For example, if I am using Cygwin and need to change directory I enter:

```
cd C:\windows\path
```

then edit this to

```
cd C:/windows/path
```

(Typically, the path is much longer than that).  Is there a way to use sed, or something else to do this automatically?  For example, I tried:

```
echo C:\windows\path|sed 's|\\|g'
```

but got the following error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated `s' command
```

My goal is to reduce the typing, so maybe I could write a program which I could call.  Ideally I would type:

```
conversionScript cd C:/windows/path
```

and this would be equivalent to typing:

```
cd C:\windows\path
```

Comment: Your `sed` command should be `sed|\\|/|g` to avoid that error.

Answer (score 28):

Thanks all.  Apparently all I need are single quotes around the path:

cd 'C:\windows\path'

and Cygwin will convert it.  Cygpath would work too, but it also needs the single quotes to prevent the shell from eating the backslash characters.

Answer (score 15):

Read about the cygpath command.

```
somecommand `cygpath -u WIN_PATH`
```

e.g.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd.exe` doesn't like single quotes. You should use double quotes

```
C:\test>echo C:\windows\path|sed "s|\\|/|g"
C:/windows/path
```

Answer (score 1):

You replace back-slash by slash using unix sed

Below I use star "*" to seperate fields in s directive

```
     sed "s*\\\*/*g"
```

The trick is to use one back-slash more than you might think needed

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question to achieve

> cd C:\windows\path

since you are in bash this just works as you want - but add single quotes

`cd 'C:\windows\path'`

As noted by @bmargulies and @Jennette - cygpath is your friend - it would be worth it to read the [cygwin man page](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygpath.html)

`man cygpath`